# Android Studio - How to remove SDK APIs From External Libraries?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have adding some SDK APIs to my project, now i need to remove them from External Libraries. So How can i do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can edit app.iml file and comment the entry `orderEntry` to remove the external libraries you don't need in your Android studio project. In my case, I want to remove all the android libraries (including Android SDK), and take that project as a pure Java project. Then I comment or remove all the following entries

```
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 21 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="appcompat-v7-21.0.3" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-annotations-21.0.3" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-v4-21.0.3" level="project" />
```

The detailed information of your project might not be the same as above, but it's similar like that to remove external libraries.

Comment: Keep in mind these values are regenerated if they are referenced in your `dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

Try File>Project Structure
There you are supposed to see Project,Libraries etc..

From SDK's you are able to remove them by pressing the "-" button.

Comment: The problem external libraries aren't displayed .. weird

Comment: Check then your build configs, if you'r using gradle check it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Why you need to remove the SDK API's from External Libraries?

In your case this is what happens, In your project you have 3 or more Modules and for each module you have set different "Module SDK". You can verify this by opening the "Project Structure" window from file menu.

In Android Studio (and in Intellij IDEA of course) you need to set a Module SDK for each modules and those module SDKs will be shown in the External Libraries section in "Project" pane. You cannot remove them.

However you can set a global "Project SDK" and then set that Poject SDK as the SDK for all modules. Then only one SDK API will be shown in "External Dependencies" (At least one SDK API will be present in "External Libraries").

Comment: **Why you need to remove the SDK API's from External Libraries?** Because i got error, after adding SDK 19, any way the problem gone after gradle sync